# Compute Coordinates of image pixel in new reference frame

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I have a bunch of images taken at different scales and sizes for each of which a certain number of facial landmarks have been manually annotated. The annotation process returns a matrix with the `(x,y)` coordinate with respect the the global reference frame of the image.

For the sake of my project I need to normalize all the images to a unique standard size (in particular `960 x 1080` pixels) and do some processing on them.

My question is:

- Given that I know the size of both the old and new image, by means of which equations for `TRANSLATION`, `ROTATION` and `SCALE` will a pixel with coordinates `(x1_1,y1_1)` in reference frame 1 be mapped into the pixel `(x2_1,y2_1)` of reference frame 2?

The image below should help clarify what I'm trying to do:

[image]

You can see 2 versions of the same image (the original `800 x 978` and the desired one `960 x 1080` ) and the positions of the landmarks of interest. Supposing I know the coordinates for all of the landmarks in the figure on the right, how do I get the equivalent coordinates for the figure on the left? (Note that the weird position of the `y` axis is due to how matlab puts the reference frames)

**ADDED PART:**

In particular the image was scaled by using `matlab's` `imresize()` function as follows:

```
B = imresize(A, [1080 960])
```

How can I compute what the scale factor was in this case?

Answer (score 3):

Let `sc = s*cos(theta)`, and `ss = s*sin(theta)` where `s` is the scaling factor, and `theta` is the rotation angle
Then for the inverse problem, the transform matrix is

```
      Tinv = [sc -ss  0;
              ss  sc  0;
              tx  ty  1]
```

where `tx` and `ty` are translations along x and y axis, respectively.

The image processing toolbox in R2013b includes [more details](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/examples/find-image-rotation-and-scale-using-automated-feature-matching.html), along with the corresponding matching functions for your reference.

**EDIT for ADDED PART**

in the `'Scale'` option of `imresize`,if you specify a vector, `imresize` uses the individual values as the scale factors for the row and column dimensions, respectively. So the scale factor is `1080/800`, and `960/978` for the row and column.

Comment: I understand. Thanks for your answer. But how will I get the values for `theta` `s` and `tx,ty`?

Comment: @Matteo Thank you Matteo. Basically you need to solve three linear equations to get the rotation, scaling, and translation respectively, with your known coordinates. SO doesn't support math expression typing, instead, I found a web page that you may be interested in: http://www.cs.mtu.edu/~shene/COURSES/cs3621/NOTES/geometry/geo-tran.html

Comment: can you let me know if you can answer the second part?Thanks